# Under which conditions is the functor $i\mapsto N(I/i)$ flat?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I refer to the composition
$$
I \xrightarrow{\quad I/-\quad} {\bf Cat} \xrightarrow{\quad N \quad} {\bf sSet},
$$
obviously. I'm asking under which conditions each comma category $(X\downarrow N(I/-))$ ($X$ any simplicial set) is cofiltered.

Comment: Isn't this always true?

Comment: This would imply that (as soon as you can write hocolim as a weighted colimit) hocolim always commutes with finite limits: is it true?

Comment: ah, probably not.  I didn't realize you meant for each simplicial set X.

Comment: If we take $X$ to be the empty set, doesn't this imply that $I$ itself must be cofiltered? So that's at least necessary. dunno whether it's sufficient